# How do I debug my server side code in an SSL environment?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, ssl

I'm writing a Silverlight application and I'm wanting to debug my custom `UserNamePasswordValidator`.  Since the validator requires SSL (for good reason), I cannot figure out how to debug it. I can't seem to use SSL against the ASP.NET Developement Server associated with Visual Studio 2010.  Since it is server sided, I can't attach Visual Studio's debugger to the process.  How on earth do I debug this thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest [trying IIS Express](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx), which can utilize SSL and/or [localtest.me](http://readme.localtest.me/) (which has ssl cert for download).

Comment: I'd really like to work through the ASP.NET Developement Server, but I guess you can't.  Alright.

Comment: I was able to create a `DebugSSL` configuration in Visual Studio 2010 that works but I have to switch manually from using ASP.NET Dev Server to IIS express.  I don't suppose there is a way to set this in the configuration explicitly.  Is there?

Answer (score 0):

- You can attach the VS debugger to IIS.  Select Debug, Attach to Process, check Show all processes, attach to w3wp.exe.  (VS must be running elevated.)
- If you want to look at the HTTP communication between your app and the server, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) will allow you to do that.  Read the [docs about HTTPS decryption](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IIS Express can be configured to be the default web server for a web project in VS 2010 SP1.  It is on the Web tab of the site project's Properties page, under Servers:

Right-click project, select Properties.  Select Web tab.  Select 'Use Local IIS Web Server'  Check [Jason Shaver's blog](http://www.jasonrshaver.com/post/2011/09/28/WP7-Client-Certificates-Part-2-(Client-Certs-on-the-Browser).aspx) for details on updating applicationhost.config (in User\Documents\IISExpress\config):

I had to change the Project Url field on that Properties tab to the value identified in applicationhost.config in order for Debug/F5 to run in SSL.

Just started playing with this, so I don't know if you can set this VS-wide instead of project by project.